# Remove duplicate values from the ordered list without `in` or `set` keywords

Tags: python, list

i am trying to remove duplicate values from ordered list without using IN or SET keywords

I have the following code, it removes the first occurrence of duplicates value, but not the second duplicate value

```
def remove_duplicates(list1):
    new_list = list(list1)
    indx = 0
    while indx+1 < len(new_list):
        if new_list[indx] == new_list[indx+1] :
             new_list.pop(indx)
        indx += 1
    return new_list
```

with one duplication it works:

```
>>> remove_duplicates([1,2,3,3,4])
[1,2,3,4]
```

but not with three duplications:

```
>>> remove_duplicates([1,2,3,3,3,4])
[1,2,3,3,4]
```

as i know when you pop the value from the list it also reduces the size of by 1

any suggestions.

Comment: The list is ordered (as in your example) or not ? duplicate values can appear in random or adjacent places ?

Comment: @mkriheli The question only states _"remove duplicate values from ordered list"_. It doesn't seems to have the requirement for the final list to be ordered like the original one. This _might_ be best though (?)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
>>>uniq = {}
>>>filter(lambda x:uniq.update({x:1}),[1,2,3,3,3,4])
>>> print uniq.keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can use `map` alternatively.

Comment: @Gnouc You took it from another side, creative approach. It inspired me to my one line answer using `dict`. Thanks. Anyway, it is very close to using `set`, we are just using `set` dressed as keys of `dict`.

Comment: What is another side? I did it my own

Comment: @Gnouc Another side means, your solution is looking to the problem in original way from side, others were not able event to think about it exists. It was compliment to the way you did it. I like it and you inspired me by that. Thanks.

Comment: @Jan Vlcinsky: Sorry for my poor English. I make this answer from Perl side: grep { ! $seen{$_}++ }  qw( 1  1 2 3 4 4 5 )

Answer (score 3):

## Using dictionary keys

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(lst).keys()
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

The trick is, that a dictionary allows only unique keys, so creating a dictionary from names with duplicated key names results in having only unique set of them.

Having list of values:

```
>>> lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
```

we create a dictioary using list values as keys:

```
>>> dct = dict.fromkeys(lst)
>>> dct
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 5: None}
```

As all the key names can be present only ones:

```
>>> dct.keys()
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

We have what is needed.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(lst).keys()
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

I have to admit, that even though it is not using `set`, using `dict` keys is very similar approach.

Comment: Is there something that guaranteed keys being ordered? [According to the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), it is not (at least with CPython): "Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random"

Comment: @SylvainLeroux You are correct, the order of keys is likely to be different than in the input list. Thinking of exact requirements, it is asking for removing duplicate items, while all solutions are simply returning new list.

Answer (score 2):

## Using generator

```
>>> def remove_duplicates(iterable):
...     last_val = iterable.next()
...     yield last_val
...     for itm in iterable:
...         if itm != last_val:
...             last_val = itm
...             yield last_val
...
>>> lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
>>> list(remove_duplicates(iter(lst)))
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Generator yields values one by one.

The initial value is yielded before the loop starts.

The `remove_duplicates` requires an iterable, so the call needs to call `iter(lst)` if passing a
list. Another option would be to do it inside of the generator, but my decision was to do it
outside.

The `list` in:

```
list(remove_duplicates(iter(lst)))
```

is to force the generator yielding all the values out.

Answer (score 2):

## Using groupby

In short:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
>>> map(lambda grpitm: grpitm[0], groupby(lst))
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Step by step:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
>>> list(groupby, lst)
[(1, <itertools._grouper at 0x7f759f976a90>),
 (2, <itertools._grouper at 0x7f759f976ad0>),
 (3, <itertools._grouper at 0x7f759f976b10>),
 (5, <itertools._grouper at 0x7f759f976b50>)]
```

`groupby` returns an iterator, which yields tuple (groupname, grouitemiterator).

For our task, we care only about groupname:

```
>>> map(lambda grpitm: grpitm[0], groupby(lst))
```

This takes each tuple returned from `groupby` and pick only the first element from it.

Note, that in Pyhton 3.x you have to put `map` into `list` to see the values:

```
>>> list(map(lambda grpitm: grpitm[0], groupby(lst)))
```

Answer (score 1):

My turn to try to solve that interesting *"Sunday Python puzzle"*:

```
>>> def remove_duplicates(lst):
...     result = [x for x,n in zip(lst,lst[1:]+[lst[0:1]]) if x != n]
...     return result if result or not lst else lst[0:1]
... 
>>> lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> 
>>> lst = [5, 5]
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[5]
>>> 
>>> lst = [5]
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[5]
>>> 
>>> lst = []
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[]
```

This answer has the property of conserving the original list order.

One might say I should have used [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip). And she/he would be probably right. But, hey, its Sunday .... so let's pretend I'm using Python 3.

Comment: @SylvianLeroux Nice excercise. Definitely not for my production code, but very tasty for Sunday Python puzzle game. Did you consider using `itertools.cycle` being forwarded by one `.next()`? It would work as "rewind one position on" and serve your nice `if x != n` filter.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Of course, not for production code! Concerning `itertools.cycle` that would be a good idea, but surprisingly enough, I couldn't come to a 1 or 2 statement solutions.  As for "Sunday Python Puzzle Game" -- if the question is good enough (that is simple but "tricky", and having many potential solutions) and clearly labeled as a "Puzzle Game", this might become a weekly rendez-vous. As this is summer, I bet it could have decent adhesion from SO peoples (?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def remove_duplicates(list1):
    new_list = list(list1)
    indx = 0
    while indx+1 < len(new_list):
        if new_list[indx] == new_list[indx+1] :
            new_list.pop(indx)
        else:
            indx += 1
    return new_list
```

The way you have it now, if you detect a duplicate as part of a triple, it will remove the middle element, then advance the index to so it's at the last element. Then, the first and the last never get compared. This way only increments the index if it doesn't detect a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As I think there is no limit on the number of answers for this *"Sunday Python Puzzle"*, here is my second attempt. As a matter of fact, it should have been the first, since this puzzle is a perfect candidate for [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). I don't know how I could have missed that for so long. But, hey, it is still Sunday...

```
>>> def remove_duplicates(lst):
...     return reduce(lambda x,n: (x + [n]) if [n] != x[-1:] else x, lst, [])
... 
>>> lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> 
>>> lst = [5, 5]
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[5]
>>> 
>>> lst = [5]
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[5]
>>> 
>>> lst = []
>>> print remove_duplicates(lst)
[]
```